# Encrypt & obfuscate filenames

Tags: encryption, software-rec, hashsum

I am looking for a backup solution and while trying to anonymize and protect my data one of the problems I've found is that the filenames leak a lot of information.

I am looking for a piece of software that can encrypt a directory of files creating **one encrypted file per actual file** so that each can be downloaded individually without wasting bandwith while also hashing the filename in such a way so that each file can be easily identified and converted to its original form given the encryption key and the hash dictionary

Comment: What Unix are you wanting to do this on?

Comment: @Kusalananda Linux, preferably something that works on all major distros.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the fuse filesystem **encfs** to do this simply. Install rpm `fuse-encfs` or apt package `encfs` and use `encfs --reverse` to mount an encrypted version of any directory, eg `/tmp/mycleardata`, at a new point, eg `/tmp/crypt-view`. Backup this directory in your usual way, and then unmount the fuse filesystem. You also need to backup the `.encfs6.xml` that will have been added to your original directory, and remember the password you used when `encfs` asked you for one.  When you want to update the backup, do the same commands. This will re-use the `.encfs6.xml` file and need the same password.

Here's an example script to play with. Obviously, normally you do not provide the password inline, and you do not normally destroy the `.encfs6.xml` file.

```
# create some test data directory
mkdir -p /tmp/mycleardata/dira
date > /tmp/mycleardata/dira/filea
date > /tmp/mycleardata/fileb
# mount an encrypted view. encfs asks for a config (blank line) and pw
mkdir -p /tmp/crypt-view
if [ -f /tmp/mycleardata/.encfs6.xml ]
then encfs --stdinpass --reverse /tmp/mycleardata /tmp/crypt-view <<\!
mypassword
!
else encfs --stdinpass --reverse /tmp/mycleardata /tmp/crypt-view <<\!

mypassword
mypassword
!
fi

# show files, do a backup
ls -ltRA /tmp/mycleardata/
ls -ltR /tmp/crypt-view
rsync -a /tmp/crypt-view/ /tmp/mybackup
# remove the crypted view
fusermount -u /tmp/crypt-view
ls -ltR /tmp/mybackup

# restore from backup. use encfs to mount backup and show clear view
mkdir -p /tmp/newclear
ENCFS6_CONFIG=/tmp/mycleardata/.encfs6.xml encfs --stdinpass /tmp/mybackup /tmp/newclear <<\!
mypassword
!
ls -ltR /tmp/newclear # should be same as original dir
fusermount -u /tmp/newclear # remove clear view
```

Here's an example of the resulting filenames:

```
/tmp/mybackup:
-rw-r--r-- 1 meuh     30 May 14 17:40 42eg5KinDst09lDzN4YNRAIG
-rw-r--r-- 1 meuh   1264 May 14 17:32 bj5Su3csNAALZEAJEB,CazsC
drwxr-xr-x 2 meuh     60 May 14 17:18 sJzZa,U7Oeyfq2j8tfeLqkm,
/tmp/mybackup/sJzZa,U7Oeyfq2j8tfeLqkm,:
-rw-r--r-- 1 meuh     30 May 14 17:40 q-c1AOYzAcy06HJ8klCZewsD
```

Note this **security message** from the encfs package installation:

> According to a security audit by Taylor Hornby (Defuse Security), the
>     current implementation of Encfs is vulnerable or potentially vulnerable
>     to multiple types of attacks. For example, an attacker with read/write
>     access to encrypted data might lower the decryption complexity for
>     subsequently encrypted data without this being noticed by a legitimate
>     user, or might use timing analysis to deduce information.
>
> Until these issues are resolved, encfs should not be considered a safe
>     home for sensitive data in scenarios where such attacks are possible.

You might also look at **ecryptfs**, which can optionally encrypt filenames, and **duplicity** which encrypts rsync.

Comment: There's also eCryptfs, but not as easy to set up as Encfs. I think the "security message" for Encfs is a little overdramatic, all encryption is potentially vulnerable to some attacks, especially if the attacker has read-write access multiple times - if it's a personal device then installing spyware would be a much bigger threat than breaking EncFS. It may not be ideal for online storage though